# js не анимируются элементы

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

В моём скрипте функция анимирует появление блока на странице путём увеличения его высоты. Анимация реализована заменой класса  элемента. Но блок не анимируется, а сразу переходит в конечное состояние. Другими словами анимация просто пропускается. Но если ввести команду замены класса элемента в консоль, то блок плавно появляется на странице, то есть всё работает так как нужно. Ниже представлены описание классов и фрагмент когда, который некорректно отрабатывает в скрипте. Подскажите пожалуйста возможные причины такого поведения элемента.

```
//Css
.disactive{
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 0;
}
.animate{
    max-height: 500px;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 15px;
    transition-property: max-height, padding-top, padding-bottom, background-color;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
//JS
document.querySelector('.disactive').classList.replace('disactive', 
'animate');
```

P.S. данный фрагмент когда выполняется в самом конце функции, и после него никакие другие функции не вызываются. То есть порядок выполнения этого фрагмента в скрипте и через консоль одинаков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в `DOM` элемент попадает сразу с классом `animate` и ничего не знает про первоначальное состояние, все что нужно сделать - отложить добавление класса с анимацией

```js
setTimeout(e => document.querySelector('.disactive')
                        .classList.replace('disactive','animate'));
```

```css
.disactive{
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    background-color:wheat;
}

.animate{
    max-height: 500px;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 15px;
    background-color:red;
    transition-property: max-height, padding-top, padding-bottom, background-color;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="disactive"></div>
```